# Page is loading at middle of page because of iframe

Tags: iframe, load

A page that I am working on is loading where the iframe is dropped instead of loading at the top as it normally would. I suspect it's due to the url of the iframe source having a "#" in it. The url is: http://icba.ac360.aristotleactioncenter.com/#/searchForMe

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the iFrame within a block using the `<div>` tag.

`<div style='float:(direction left or right);width:(percentage)%'>`

Keep in mind that if you make several blocks float left they will stack against each other in the order that they are in the code. The width is determinate of the line break positions on your div blocks and you can turn iFrames or blocks of text into columns by setting smaller widths in your style.
 (%= % of width of page break is on). Also, be sure to place the block in the head nav or body.
(idk if this will work)